# FullCalendar - display google calendar not working

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, fullcalendar-5

I've been trying to integrate my google calendar inside of [FullCalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/).

My code without the google integration looks like the following:

```
<div id="calendarElem">
<link href='fullcalendar/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='fullcalendar/main.js'></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendarElem');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
    });
    calendar.render();
});
       
</script>
</div>
```

Using that code, I'm getting an empty calendar - so far so good.

Then I tried following [the docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar) to integrate the google calendar.

I went and created an API key for Google Calendar, made my calendar public and copied the URL to it.

Then, using the following code, I got an error saying "googleCalendarPlugin is not defined":

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        plugins: [ googleCalendarPlugin ],
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'aGeneratedKey',
        events: {
            googleCalendarId: 'myCalendarURL'
        }
    });
```

I then tried to simply remove the plugin from there, which solved the previous problem, however, now I get the result from Google, saying that my API key is not correct.... This might make sense, because I couldn't follow the exact procedure from Fullcalendar, as in the docs, it says to create a "browser key", however, Google only provided me with the possibility to create a OAuth client ID or a service account, not to create a browser key...

Does anybody have an idea how to get this working?

Or does anybody know a good alternative to display your google calendar on a website (except using the iframe method provided by google, because no styling is possible for that)?

**EDIT**: seems like I somehow managed to create an API key that works for the calendar... However, now I'm getting a 404, I guess this means that the `googleCalnedarID` is not correct...might be the case, because it looks completely different from what the docs show as well..

Comment: glad you got most of it working though. We can't help you with the calendar ID, we don't know your ID. However you can easily [find out how to work it out](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+discover+my+google+calendar+ID). Also, you have to make sure the calendar is marked as public, did you do that?

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the help! I found it and got it working :) However, it doesn't look like in the docs, its simply my email-adress. So the docs are outdated when inlcuding the plugin, when creating the API key as well as for finding the calendar ID...

Comment: No the docs aren't outdated in respect of the ID. Your primary calendar always is your email address. But if you create a secondary calendar inside the same Google account then it will have an ID in the style shown. I can't comment if they're correct in terms of obtaining an API key, I haven't tried to do it for a while. Anyway fullCalendar have a page on their website with instructions for how you can report problems such as bugs and errors in the docs, so if you want to let them know, check out that page and follow the instructions.

Comment: @ADysonwell, the saction is also not called calendar address and if it is as described, they should mention that as well, because I searched a lot there. And yes, I reported the problem on GitHub :)